# Limit of $(n+1)^a-n^a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Im asked to prove the $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x+1)^a-x^a=0$ when $a<1$. I was going to do this in three steps, when $0\lt a \lt 1$, when $a=0$ and when $a<0$. Im unsure now that I think about it. It may have to do with Bernoulli's inequality $(1+x)^a\ge1+ax$ or with the mean value theorem.

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $a < 0$
it is clear,
since both terms go to zero.

When $a = 0$,
it is 1 - 1 = 0.

The only case left is
$0 < a < 1$.
In that case,
$(x+1)^a-x^a
=x^a((1+1/x)^a-1)
$.

A useful inequality here is this:
if $0 < y < a < 1$ then
$(1+\frac{y}{a})^a
\le \frac1{1-y}
$.
This can be shown 
in a number of ways,
one of which is
to compare terms
in the
generalized binomial theorem.

From this we have
$(1+1/x)^a
=(1+(a/x)/a)^a
\le \frac1{1-a/x}
=\frac{x}{x-a}
$,
so

$\begin{array}\\
(x+1)^a-x^a
&=x^a((1+1/x)^a-1)\\
&\le x^a(\frac{x}{x-a}-1)\\
&=x^a\frac{a}{x-a}\\
&=\frac{ax^a}{x-a}\\
&\to 0
\text{ as }x \to \infty
\text{ since } 0 < a < 1\\
\end{array}
$.