# Show $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\bigr( (x+1)^{2H} - x^{2H}}\bigr) = 0$ for $0 \lt H \lt 1/2$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to show $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\bigr( (x+1)^{2H} - x^{2H}}\bigr) = 0$ for $0 \lt H \lt 1/2$.

I believe this has something to do with the fact $x \mapsto x^{2H}$ is concave for $0 \lt H \lt 1/2$ but I cant seem to use the concavity property to prove this.

Comment: There is a simple solution using the mean value theorem.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1542334/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2935293/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1048911/42969.

Comment: Concavity is not sufficient: $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-1}$ is concave, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+1) -f(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem)
$$(1+x)^{2H}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom {2H} k x^k$$
where $\binom m k = \frac{m(m-1)\cdots(m-k+1)}{k!}$. So Al remained members will have power  $\leqslant 2H-1$ and limit gives zero. One moment, that I want leave for you, with hope you can manage it, is interchanging limit and summation.

Answer (score 0):

For [concave differentiable $f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Functions_of_a_single_variable) we have: $$f(y)-f(x)\leq f'(x)(y-x).$$
In this case $f(x)=x^{2H}$ and $f'(x)=2Hx^{2H-1}$ decreases to $0$ at $\infty$ for $0<H<1/2$. Taking $y=x+1$ gives: $$0\leq(x+1)^{2H} - x^{2H}\leq2Hx^{2H-1}(x+1-x)\\=\frac{2H}{x^{1-2H}}\to0$$ when $x\to\infty$. By the squeeze theorem, the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

We must assume $\;x>0$, otherwise $\;x^{2H}\;$ may not be defined (and on the other hand $\;x\to+\infty...$).

The Lagrange's mean theorem applied to the function $\;f(x)=x^{2H}\;$ in the interval $\;[x,x+1]\;$ gives

\begin{align}
\big|(x+1)^{2H}&-x^{2H}\big| \leq \sup_{\xi\in[x,x+1]}\big|Df(\xi)\big|\cdot\big|x+1-x\big| = \\[1ex]
&= \sup_{\xi\in[x,x+1]}\,\big|2H\xi^{2H-1}\big| = \\[1ex]
&= \frac{2H}{\inf_{\xi\in[x,x+1]\,}\xi^{1-2H}} = \\[1ex]
&= \frac{2H}{x^{1-2H}} \to 0 \quad \text{as }\; x\to+\infty
\end{align}
being $\,1-2H>0$.

We conclude by the squeeze theorem and by observing that, in general, for any $\,g\,$ and $\;a\;$we have
$$ \lim_{x\to a}\big|g(x)\big|=0 \;\implies\; \lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0. $$